# Golang type conversion between slice of pointers to slice of a type to slice of another

Tags: go, casting, type-conversion, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am new to Golang.
When I try it I get a compile error:

```
cannot use a.B (type []*C) as type []Z in field value
```

Code:

```
package main

type A struct {
    B []*C
}

type C struct {
    char string
}

type X struct {
    Y []Z
}

type Z struct {
    char string
}

func doSomething(r interface{}) X {
    a := r.(*A)
    return X{
        Y: a.B, // cannot use a.B (type []*C) as type []Z in field value
    }
}

func main() {
    something := &C{"abc"}
    somewhere := A{}
    somewhere.B = []*C{something}

    doSomething(somewhere)
}
```

The way I am thinking of getting around is by iterating over the slice and assigning it to another. But I know there must be other ways to do it.

Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/v0PUTPh6Mt

Comment: no, there are no other (safe) ways to do it. Slices are invariant, and you have to copy them to change the type of each element. It's the same concept as https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `for` loop for convert each value in slice. no other way

https://play.golang.org/p/oQi6oVz6My